# Is it always safe to shift bool values?

Tags: c++, c, compiler, boolean

I stumbled about a Cppcheck warning (an inconclusive one), that I mistakenly used `&` instead of `&&`:

```
/// @param code identifies the command. Only the lower 16 bits of are being processed
int encodeCmdState(bool finished, int code, bool errorneous)
{
    return
        (finished & 1) |
        ((code & 0xffff)<<1) |
        ((err & 1)<< 17);
}
```

I'm not sure if this code (style) reaches back into times where `bool` wasn't available in C. My first idea would be to simply strip the `& 1` normalization from the `bool` parts. But I want to be sure, so...

Is shifting `bool` values "portable" and "safe"? Or, more generally:

Does the **implicit** `bool`-to-`int` conversation in arithmetic expressions **always normalize** values?

Comment: Bit manipulation is much easier to reason about if you just convert everything to `unsigned` beforehand.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Maybe, BTW: the posted example is a simplified extract of the real code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the C++ standard, §4.5 ad. 6 (On integral promotions):

> A prvalue of type bool can be converted to a prvalue of type int, with
>   false becoming zero and true becoming one.

According to the C++ standard, §4.7 ad. 4 (On integral conversions):

> If the destination type is bool, see 4.12. If the source type is bool,
>   the value false is converted to zero and the value true is converted
>   to one.

So a boolean `true` is always converted to 1, and a boolean `false` is always converted to 0, during integral promotion and conversion.

As an example take a look at this simple and naive example (http://ideone.com/kgxrTW):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    bool a = true;
    bool b = false;
    cout << "a = " << a << endl;
    cout << "b = " << b << endl;
    cout << boolalpha << "a = " << a << endl;
    cout << boolalpha << "b = " << b << endl;

    int c = a << 1;
    int d = b << 1;
    bool e = a << 1;
    cout << "c = " << c << endl;
    cout << "d = " << d << endl;
    cout << "e = " << e << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output of which will be:

```
a = 1
b = 0
a = true
b = false
c = 2
d = 0
e = true
```

Comment: I unaccepted this answer for rethinking [my last experiences](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/269311/106929) (there is a difference between *the C++ standard* and the every-day job I was referring as *always*)

Comment: I finally accept this answer: The compiler is not responsible for repairing uninitialized/manipulated/corrupted memory. Although some compilers *are* broken for some cases of integer promotion. If in doubt, test!

Answer (score 1):

As [TommyA pointed out](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/269289/106929), it is safe, at least *under normal circumstances*.

But caution is necessary if you deal with unchecked assignments of `bool` values (from input), for example when copying memory portions (naive IPC approaches using `struct`s), I expected this to be possibly a problem. So I created this simple test case,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int b2i(bool v)
{
    return v << 1;
}

int main() {
    bool v = true;
    cout << "v = " << v << endl;
    cout << "b2i(v) = " << b2i(v) << endl;

    // simulating input:
    memset(&v, -1, sizeof v);

    cout << "b2i(v) = " << b2i(v) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and tried it with some compilers. Indeed, the outputs differ.

**[C++14](http://ideone.com/Skb6k0) and [C++ 4.9.2](http://ideone.com/CDQrU2):**

```
v = 1
b2i(v) = 2
b2i(v) = 2
```

**[C++ 4.3.2](http://ideone.com/Fk6ZuS)** (also in Borland 0x0564):

```
v = 1
b2i(v) = 2
b2i(v) = 510
```